# Windows Admintrator/Access Right Issue

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator, desktop

My newly installed computer has some access right or administrative right issue.  Due to this issue, I need always click Yes/Allow button, this is annoying.

---

My Window Account is Administrator and it is Window 7 Professional and desktop.

(1)
When I try to copy the backup folders/files from an external drive to the computer, the dialog says access deny and require admin right to continue. The pop-up warning is "You'll need to provide administrator permission to move this folder".  After copying by clicking "continue" enabling admin access, every time I use (edit/delete/move) the files, the problem still exist, it requires admin access again. This is annoying. These files are not system files, just normal user things.

How can I make the computer properly recognize/remember which files need admin-right access, and which files are normal user files?

(2)
Similarly problem appear on running some software which make changes to computer (e.g. Symantec).  Every time, it ask "Do you want to allow the following program to make the changes to this computer?".  I click "Yes" to allow.  I am adminstrator, it would implement immediately after click Yes/Allow, not need login as administrator again. Why it need ask permission?  And it cannot remember my option and ask again every time I use.

Another similar warning is ".... runs as a Windows Service, requiring Administrative privileges.  Click the Allow button below to install and start running the service using elevated privileges."

How can I make the computer properly remember my option? Any security level would be set?

P.S.
If I use command and run in "Administrator Command Prompt", everything work properly
[(see image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbfny.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel

1. Switch view by category to small icons. For easy access.
2. Click on User accounts.
3. You see the option.  `Change User Account Control Settings` click on that.
4. Drag the bar to end for `never notify`. Click on Ok.

Check the Image below for your Reference

[image]

Comment: This setting just reduce the notifications.  Some software still cannot run and even no pop-up window for clicking "Allow" or "Yes".  Then I need right click "run as Administrators"

Comment: User is having administrator rights??

Comment: 1.Right click on the application.then select Properties from the menu.    2.click on Compatibility tab then check the box showing 'Run it as Administrator's lick Apply and then OK            It is always good to keep UAC enabled. it protects your PC from many security threats.

Comment: User is having administrator rights?? Yes

Comment: When I click "Allow" or "Yes" (to grant right) or  "run as Administrators", It  don't have"login" dialog and don't need enter administrator+password

Comment: No as it's admin permission user. It takes automatically.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. The problem is not notification level. It is not even remotely related to whether the user has administrative right. The problem is the OP's Windows wrongly requiring administrative privilege on normal user actions.